# Firebase storage use getDownloadURL vs store download link

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm uploading images to Firebase Storage.

What would be a better approach to show the image in my app?

Use the `getDownloadURL` on `imageRef` like so:

```
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
final imagesRef = storageRef.child("images/image.jpg");
final String downloadLink = imagesRef.getDownloadURL();
```

Or saving the downloadLink (when putting the file in storage) is Firestore DB?

The motivation for this is to access thumbnails:

1. An image is uploaded to the storage
2. A cloud function is generating a thumbnail
3. Instead of saving the thumbnail download link, it can be retrieved using the sample code

like so:

```
final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
final thumbRef = storageRef.child("images/thumb_image.jpg");
final String downloadLink = imagesRef.getDownloadURL();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to display the image once, then you can only use the `downloadURL` when you upload the image to Cloud Storage. If you need to display the image more than once, then you can store the image URL either in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), and get it from there whenever you need it.

**Edit:**

When you display an image only once, then there is no need to save the URL in a database, because you'll get it in the callback when the upload to Cloud Storage operation completes. If you need to display the image sometime later, you don't have to upload the image again, in order to display it, you can only grab the URL from the database and display the image.

Comment: can you explain why it depends in the number of times this image is displayed?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: but you can still get the download URL, using storage ref and getDownloadURL (please see my example), and that can be done even after the initial upload. It requires an extra call to Firestore, but saves the need to store the downloadURL. So my question is if this is a valid technique, or is it better to always save the downloadURL?

Comment: Yes, but you also need to store the path of the file somewhere. So instead of storing the path,  the best option that you have is to save the URL in an online database. That's also a valid technique, but it's not recommended to have dynamic data in your application code. Only constants should be saved in the application's code. Is it ok now?

Comment: Actually, the DB path can be "computed" ( _users/[userID]/avatar and _users/[userID]/avatar_thumb ). is that what you mean by "dynamic data in your application code"?

Comment: If you can create the path to a file using only the data that you already have in your application code, then there is no need to save something in the database. You can directly get the download URL.

Comment: indeed, but it requires an extra call (to get the download URL) - so this got me wondered...

Comment: Yes, that's an extra call to Storage. That indeed it's an async call.